# Loop funcionando somente para a primeira linha shell script

Tags: shell-script

Preciso fazer um script que leia uma lista de querys de um arquivo txt, e salve o resultado de cada query em um arquivo com o nome da tabela.

O meu script ficou assim:

```
#!/bin/bash
oIFS="$IFS"
IFS=;

QUERYS="`cat /tmp/querys.txt`"

for query in $QUERYS
do
    TABELA=`echo $QUERYS|awk -F"from" '{print $2}'|cut -d' ' -f2`
    `mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -P3307 damasio_dados -e "$query" > /tmp/$TABELA`
    done

IFS="$oIFS"
```

Se meu arquivo "/tmp/querys.txt" tiver o seguinte conteudo:

> select * from wmsstk ;

Funciona corretamente e gera o arquivo "/tmp/wmsstk" corretamente com o resultado da select.

Porém se o arquivo tiver o seguinte conteúdo:

```
select * from wmsstk ;
select * from wmsadd ;
```

Está gerando o arquivo "/tmp/wmsadd?wmsstk" com o conteudo das duas selects.

**Obs.:** Sei que talvez tenha um jeito mais simples de fazer, porém foi a forma que consegui ter algum avanço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionou com pequenas alterações, basicamente no IFS e utilizando a var $query em TABELA

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
QUERYS=$(cat /tmp/querys.txt)

for query in $QUERYS
do
    TABELA=$(echo $query|awk '{print $4}')
    $(mysql -pSENHA -uroot -h 127.0.0.1 -P3307 damasio_dados -e "$query" > /tmp/$TABELA)

done
```

PS: no meu exemplo precisei passar a senha do MySQL. Se não precisar no seu caso, retire o -pSENHA.

Comment: Confundi as variaveis $query e $QUERYS no loop mesmo...
A grande sacada foi o $IFS que eu não sabia bem como utilizar..

Agora o comando (gambiarra) pra pegar o nome da tabela, eu fiz daquele jeito porque nem sempre minha string vai ser "select * from", pode ser que às vezes tenha somente as colunas que preciso. Isso que não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer. 
De qualquer forma funcionou.

Comment: Entendi! então pode utilizar o teu modo para pegar o nome da tabela.
Se te ajudou, marque "esta resposta é útil" na setinha para cima da resposta!